# How does a custom view know its visible rect changed when it's in a scrollview?

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

Now I have a `CustomView` and its width is large, So I put it into a `HorizontalScrollView`. To make better performance, I just draw the visible rect of this view in its `onDraw()` method. Now I face a issue that when I scroll the view using my finger, how does the view know that its visible rect has been changed and refresh its content by calling `postInvalidate()`.

Thanks a lot if someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

ScrollView should automatizovaly draw view when it scrolls into visible region. You dont need to call postInvalidate(). You should invalidate your view only when content of your view has changed and needs to be redrawn. Dont worry about scroll view. If you want to avoid executing unnecessary drawing code for stuff that is not visible, use quickReject methods of Canvas in your onDraw(). Or getClipBounds method of Canvas to find out what part of your view is currently visible.

Comment: But when I scroll my view, the method onDraw() isn't called at all. In my issue, the CustomView is the only view in ScrollView.

Comment: @Nick inside `onSraw` call `Log.d` and log the value of `canvas.getClass()`, what do you see on the logcat? is it `android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas` or something similar?

Comment: @pskink , I do as you said and the type of `canvas` is `android.view.DisplayListCanvas`.

Comment: @Nick ok now change your manifest `<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false">`and run your app again, also `Log.d` the value of `canvas.isHardwareAccelerated()`

Comment: @pskink, Now it's `android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas` and `canvas.isHardwareAccelerated() is false. Then, what should I do?

Comment: @Nick see if `onDraw` is called as you scroll your view

Comment: I dont think it is good idea to turn of hardware acceleration. Maybe it would be the best just to leave view render as a whole. Scroll view is probably caching rendered view in hardware layer or it is caching at least display list for your view and thats why you are not getting onDraw calls when scrolling. GPU will automatically clip non visible parts from your display list. There is probably no reason to worry about manually optimizing code in your on draw, since it actually does not get to be called to often.

Comment: of course  turning off hardware acceleration is a bad idea: i just showed that if it is **on** `onDraw` is called once and no optimization is needed, if it is **off** then getting the clip rect & quickReject is helpful in such case

Comment: My `CustomView` is voice volume wave view and it is updated all the time when user is recording voice. The volume is updated every 100ms, And so, I must do below code in `onDraw()` every 100ms. Notice that `tColumnCount` is increased all the time. 

`
for (int i = 0; i < tColumnCount; i++) {
   .......
}
`

@pskink, @snapix, I want to do some optimization, what can I do?

Comment: @Nick for such a view i would use `SurfaceView` / `TextureView`

Comment: @pskink, thank you for your help, I'll try TextureView later. Thank you.